# How to get the directions north/south/east/west with google maps api?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

for example I have 5 markers and I want to get the direction (E,W,NE etc) for each one of them according to the main one(red in the center). Here is a pic. Is there a way to do this with google.maps.DirectionsService or calculate it somehow?
Thank you.

[image]

**Upd:Here is what I get:**

```
m.position.lng() - c.position.lng()
m.position.lat() - c.position.lat()
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let me give the idea.
You can use `slope`. Assume you have a marker `M1` and center marker `C`.
`Slope` should be equal to `(C.lat - C.lng)/(M1.lat - M1.lng)`
If the slope happens to be nearly 0 it can be either East or West if `M1.lng > C.lng` it should be West.
if slope is nearly 1 it is either South West or North East. Then, if `M1.lng > C.lng` it is South West
If slope is nearly -1 it is either North West or South East. Then i `M1.lng > C.lng`, it is North West.  
You can use the same approach for other directions

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Where I can read more about this? As I don't understand how to use this approach for other directions. I can get the M1.lng > C.lng for East West direction, but if I try to use (C.lat - C.lng)/(M1.lat - M1.lng) I get some 0<res<1 or res>1 and it is some sort of diagonal line

Comment: Actually, I came up with that solution after you asked. You can ask to me which part you could not understand

Comment: So, you have problem with intermediate directions?

Comment: I have some errors in the answer let me fix that and i will explain in a more detailed way therein

Comment: I updated my question. I think I can get NE, NW, SW, SE directions with m.position.lng() - c.position.lng() and m.position.lat() - c.position.lat()

Answer (score 1):

Let's say we want to find the cardinal direction from point A to point B:

```
if (A.lat > B.lat){
   NS = "S"
} else {
   NS = "N"
}

if (A.lng > B.lng){
   EW = "W"
} else {
   EW = "E"
}

cardinal_direction = NS + EW
```

Possible `cardinal_direction` values are: SW, SE, NW, NE